# Transfer D3-UEE Xbox 360 to D3-UEE Xbox One

Tags: diablo-iii

I know that if you buy Ultimate Evil Edition for Xbox One, you can transfer your old Diablo 3 data from Xbox 360, but if you get Ultimate Evil Edition for Xbox 360 and play a while, are you able to transfer that data to Xbox One at a later point?

Comment: Pretty sure the cross saving feature applies to all versions of the game.

Comment: Export is available with Diablo 3 + ROS on PS3 and Xbox 360.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Diablo 3 Ultimate Evil Edition has an export function to export saves between previous generation, and current generation of consoles. Blizzard have said so in the FAQ section of the original feature announcement.

[Official battle.net blog](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/15058023/pick-your-platform-keep-your-save-8-18-2014#faq)